# Was Theoden's speech a reference to Hamlet?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In the second LOTR movie, Theoden says this before charging out at Helm's deep:

> Let this be the hour when we draw swords together. **Fell deeds awake.** Now for wrath, now for ruin, and the red dawn. Forth, Eorlingas!

In the books, Theoden-King delivers a similar speech/poem before the Battle of Pelenor Fields:

> Arise, arise, Riders of Théoden!
> **Fell deeds awake**, fire and slaughter!
> spear shall be shaken, shield be splintered,
> a sword-day, a red day, ere the sun rises!
> Ride now, ride now! Ride to Gondor!

In the play Hamlet, the titular character says this:

> **foul deeds will rise**,
> though all the earth o'erwhelm them, to men's eyes.

I thought it was an interesting coincidence that both authors use phrases that follow a similar formula (f adjective meaning bad/evil + deeds + verb that roughly means arising).  There are also parallels between the plots (After saying this, Theoden charges out to face his enemies and receives assistance from a wizard, and in turn Hamlet ventures out and has his own supernatural encounter)

Is it an intentional reference? Or is it just a coincidence – even though the phrasing sounds a bit unusual to my modern ears (people don't really think of deeds as being things that wake up or arise) maybe this sort of construction wasn't unusual in the older writings that Tolkien was inspired by?

Comment: The construction isn't that unusual for older writing - it also means two different things - Theoden is expressing the imminence of fell deeds (which fell does not necessarily mean *bad*, but something more like 'grim' or 'terrible'), whereas Hamlet is saying that wicked deeds can't be covered up and will always eventually come out.

Comment: As for the choice of words, "Fell deeds awake, fire and slaughter" looks to be modeled on Anglo-Saxon poetry with, in this case, first and third stresses (the two f-words) alliterating, and a caesura at the comma. (The form is not followed strictly, though, with even more alliteration than usual—all those s and r words in the latter half!)

Comment: I'd go with coincidence, but helped along by similar tropes being involved.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Christopher confirms in HoMe that these lines were echoing anglo saxon.

Comment: And if it had anything to do with a Shakespeare play, it would be _Henry V_, not _Hamlet_.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: The form is followed reasonably strictly in the rest of the speech: "Arise, arise, Riders of Théoden!  // Fell deeds awake, fire and slaughter! // spear shall be shaken, shield be splintered, // a sword-day, a red day, ere the sun rises! // Ride now, ride now! Ride to Gondor!" Five lines, each can be split in half with two stressed words in each half, and alliteration between the stressed words in each line. There's more alliteration between the lines than necessary in Anglo-Saxon poetry, but I don't think that means it deviates from the form.

Comment: @PeterShor thanks! (And nice to see a fellow mathematician over here) It definitely follows the rough form, but there was, I believe, a general rule about the fourth stressed word _not_ alliterating. But Tolkien was of course an authority, and probably knew of examples (say in Maldon) where the rules were bent, by the poet or subsequent scribes...

Comment: @DavidRoberts: I believe there was indeed a rule about the fourth word not alliterating when *Beowulf* was written; at least, *Beowulf* follows this rule. But the examples of Old English alliterative verse we know of span four centuries, and it undoubtedly evolved during this time period. The earliest example we have of it, [Caedmon's Hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A6dmon%27s_Hymn), breaks this rule. (Caveat: I'm not an expert on Old English verse.)

Comment: @Peter Me neither! I recently read *The tradition of versification in Old English* so some things were fresh in mind. Thanks for the examples ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I don't think anyone has ever tried to claim it, so I have no authoritative sources, but for starters they mean different things:

**fell deeds awake** is a command for some fierce/savage/deadly actions to begin

**foul deeds will rise [...] to men's eyes** is a warning that bad/unpleasant actions cannot be covered up and will eventually rise to the surface and be seen

Answer (score 15):

### It was a reference to the Old Norse Völuspá, not Hamlet

In *The History of Middle-earth*, when discussing the writing of this passage, Christopher Tolkien says:

> In the remainder of The Ride of the Rohirrim' the final form was achieved in this manuscript almost word for word: the speech of Wídfara about the change in the wind, the disposition of the companies of the Rohirrim, Merry's fear that the king would quail and turn back, **his great cry (with echoes of the Old Norse Völuspá) 'Arise, arise, Riders of Theoden ...'**, and the likening of Theoden to 'Orome the Great in the Battle of the Valar when the world was young.'
> <sub>The History of Middle-earth volume VIII - *The War of the Ring* - page 353</sub>

Christopher is likely referring to this stanza of the Völuspá ([translation from here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe03.htm)):

> Brœðr muno beriaz | ok at bǫnom verða,
> muno systrungar | sifiom spilla.
> Hart er í heimi, | hórdómr mikill.
> **Skeggǫld, skálmǫld, | skildir ro klofnir.**
> **Vindǫld, vargǫld, | áðr verǫld steypiz.**
> Mun engi maðr | ǫðrom þyrma.
>
> Brothers shall fight | and fell each other,
> And sisters' sons | shall kinship stain;
> Hard is it on earth, | with mighty whoredom;
> **Axe-time, sword-time, | shields are sundered,**
> **Wind-time, wolf-time, | ere the world falls;**
> Nor ever shall men | each other spare.

Incidentally, while researching this answer, I found that the TV show Vikings also used this war cry.

(It should also be noted that Tolkien would have been familiar with Hamlet, as it was one of the set texts that he had to read as an undergraduate at Oxford, and one of his final exam papers there was on Shakespeare. Tolkien also is known to have seen a performance of it in 1944 (Letters #76), has very briefly referenced it in two of his published academic lectures. However he very much didn't like Shakespeare and one of his actions as a professor was to remove him from the syllabus. It's unlikely that he would be referencing Hamlet here.)

Comment: Do you have a source on the final paragraph? That's very interesting

Comment: @RogueJedi - (1/2) It's from Hammond & Scull's *J.R.R. Tolkien: Companion and Guide* under the entry for "Shakespeare, William": *Although at university Tolkien chose to specialize in the language side of the Oxford English School, he still had to study Shakespeare: one paper of his final examinations in 1915 was devoted to that author. The set plays were Love’s Labour’s Lost, Henry IV: Part 1, Henry IV: Part 2, Hamlet, and Antony and Cleopatra, but candidates were also required to read for background* ...

Comment: (2/2) ... *and be able to answer questions such as ‘Give some account of the acting company of which Shakespeare was a member. What are the indications that in writing his plays he sometimes thought of the special abilities of the actors?’ and ‘Show how Shakespeare’s dramas reflect the experiences, and the reading of his school-days.’ After Tolkien returned to Oxford as Rawlinson and Bosworth Professor of Anglo-Saxon, he played a major role in 1930–1 in the revision of the syllabus of the English School, after which students on the language side no longer had to take a paper on Shakespeare.*